# How to solve a second order ODE with no constant coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x''(t)=a(t)x(t)$ on some time interval $[0,T]$. For a first order equation one can formally divide by $x(t)$ and hence get the solution by the exponential function. For constants coeffcients one could take the ansatz $x(t)=e^{\lambda t}$. Now both approaches do not seem to work...I would be grateful for any hints how to solve this kind of equations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible approach.  You can associate a second order linear ODE with the Ricatti equation as follows:
Let $x' = bx$.  That is, assume that $x'$ is some unknown function multiplied by itself.  Now, substitution into the equation $x'' = ax$ gives us the equation
$$(b'+b^2)x = ax \implies (b'+b^2-a)x = 0.$$
For $x$ non-trivial, $b'+b^2-a = 0$.
This is a Ricatti equation.
So, solve this equation for $b$, and then solve $x' = bx$ for $x$.

I also wanted to attach [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316088290_An_Analytical_Method_for_Solving_General_Riccati_Equation) paper from 2017, which might be a good reference to test whether your Ricatti equation can be solved analytically.

Comment: Ohh.  Yes.  This was just a typo.  Of course, it should be $x' = bx$.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: I've never seen this before but it looks very interesting. Is there a solution formula for $b'+b^2-a=0$? I couldn't figure it out. I am asking since my $a$ is already not too "beauty" which is why I don't really want to do calculations with it but rather plug it in if there is some formula

Comment: There is not a formula for solving $b'+b^2-a = 0$.  I was just giving one possible approach.  It might work, or it might not.  If you want an approximate solution, I would recommend solving it numerically (RK4 method, for example).

Comment: It's ***Riccati***. The Italian word “ricatti” is the plural of “ricatto”, that is, *blackmail*.